# Async embedded subprocess termination

Tags: activiti, bpmn

***What I have:***

'user_task_in _main_process' from which I start many *non interrupting embedded subprocesses*  by signal.

***What I want:***

When one of subprocesses achieve success, I *want to complete it and destroy all other subprocesses*. By destroy I mean stop it abruptly without further continuation.

***What a problem:***

I suggest that all async subprocesses should be ended when I complete an 'user_task_in _main_process', but they doesn't!

***Question:***

How correctly destroy async embeded subprocesses?

Comment: Do you use multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics to create subprocesses ?

Comment: No, multi-instate doesn't meet my needs. I don't know how many subprocesses I'll want to launch. So I use embedded subprocess started by the signal.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [Message](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnBoundaryMessageEvent) or [Signal Boundary Event](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnBoundarySignalEvent) at the subprocess with the option `cancelActivity="true"`.

Upon completion of the subprocess then you could implement a mechanism which could send this message/signal to the other subprocess instances and they will be cancelled.

The Message/Signal Bounday Events differ so you will have to choose which one suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nikola's answer. You should add a signal event to the end of each of your sub processes. Then, add a boundary event to the sub process containers that goes to a terminate end point.

This way, all sub processes will be initiated, and the first to complete will automatically terminate all other sub procrsses